# Button click function is not triggering on IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onclick, click, internet-explorer-11

.click() function is occurring on all browsers except IE11. I am wondering if IE cannot support this method due to using an older JS or JQuery version:

```
function bindSearchInputToBtn() {
    $('#joblist-search-partial #textValue').keyup(function (e) {

        //Enter key event 
        if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.which === 13) {

            $('#joblist-search-partial .search-button .btn-primary').click();

        }

    });
}
```

IE recognises the enter button press as well as the button, but seems to not be able to handle the click() function. Is there a way around this?

I have tried other options on SO, such as `on('click', function()` however was not successful, and think I may coming at it from the wrong angle.

New to JS, so may be missing something simple. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to call the `click` event in the first place? Just extract the function behind the `click` and call it from both click and `keyup`

Comment: @MauriceNino There is an ```onclick``` within the button which submits a form, however due to restrictions to the platform the site is on , i cannot add this form submission code to my JS function. So the idea is that I just trigger the click from my function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using old school javascript methods instead of `jQuery`. `jQuery` uses a lot of new `ES6` methods behind the scene which Internet Explorer might not know.

```
function bindSearchInputToBtn() {
    $('#joblist-search-partial #textValue').keyup(function (e) {

        //Enter key event 
        if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.which === 13) {

            let joblist = document.getElementById('#joblist-search-partial');
            let btn-primary = joblist.childNodes[0].childNodes[0] //<-- Assuming that .search-button is the first child of #joblist-search-partial and .btn-primary of .search-button
            btn-primary.click();

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work. I don't think it is an issue with finding the element though, as it is able to find the `#textValue` element on line 2. I still think it could be something to do with the `.click()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attach javascript event for multiple Html elements using the JQuery selector, you need to **add ',' between the JQuery selector**. Please refer to the following code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function bindSearchInputToBtn() {
            $('#joblist-search-partial,#textValue').keyup(function (e) {               
                //Enter key event
                if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.which === 13) {
                    $('#joblist-search-partial, .search-button, .btn-primary').click();
                }
            });
            $('#joblist-search-partial, .search-button, .btn-primary').click(function () {
                alert($(this).val())
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="bindSearchInputToBtn();">
    <input id="joblist-search-partial" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="textValue" type="text" /><br />
    <button class="btn search-button" type="button" value="Search" >Search</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Submit" >Submit</button>

</body>
```